# How can I display an image and text from an array on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Basically, I have a simple webpage with two text fields, and a button to choose an image from the computer. What I need to happen, is for the user to pick a photo, fill in the "artist" and "text" field, press the "Add image" button. This should then add all three items to an array, and display both the image in a div, and the text in an "li" list item.

At the moment, the image works, and will display on the screen when the button is pressed, the text seems to get pushed into the array, but no matter what I do, I can't get the text to display on the web page. I also couldn't get the image to display if I turned the array into objects, which is why I've split the pushing of the text to a separate function.

Either way, whatever I try, either breaks the image display, or breaks the text display. I can't get both to display on the page. I am trying to make it so whenever a new image and text is added, it will all display one after another sort of like this:

[album cover]

[text]

[album cover]

[text]

And this would carry on down the screen as you keep adding more. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong with this. Thanks.

```js
var info = {
    myImages: [],

    addImage: function(imageBlob) {
        this.myImages.push(imageBlob);
    },

    addInfo: function(artist, title) {
        this.myImages.push({
            artist: artist, 
            title: title
            });
    },


    redrawImages: function() {
        var divForImages = document.getElementById('myImages');
        divForImages.innerHTML = '';
        this.myImages.forEach((imageBlob) => {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.style.width = "200px";
            img.style.height = "200px";
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
            divForImages.appendChild(img);
        });

    },

    redrawInfo: function() {
        var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
        this.myImages.forEach(function (item) {
            let li = document.createElement('li');
            ul.appendChild(li);
            li.innerHTML += item;
        });
    }


}

var handlers = {
    addImageAndRedraw: function() {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        var artistField = document.getElementById('artistField');
        var titleField = document.getElementById('titleField');

        if (fileInput.files.length === 1) {
            info.addImage(fileInput.files[0]);
            info.addInfo(artistField.value, titleField.value);
            info.redrawImages();
            info.redrawInfo();
        }
    }
}

var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handlers.addImageAndRedraw);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My images</h1>
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="false" value="Select image">
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Add image and redraw">

    <div>
        <input id="artistField" type="text" placeholder="artist">
        <input id="titleField" type="text" placeholder="title">
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div id="myImages">
    </div>


    <ul></ul>

    <script src="album.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to look at [[How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992) to make it easier for others to see and work with your code.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - I will keep that in mind for future questions, thanks.

Comment: You're adding the info to the same array as the images, so it will end up like `[image, info, image, info]` etc..  You're better off adding an object that contains both the image and the info, and then treating it as a single object when you add the contents to the page, rather than adding the images and text in separate functions.  Also, you're not clearing the info list, so it would grow exponentially.

Comment: @Archer - I thought that was probably the case, but was having difficulties adding the text and the image in the same function as it was then not displaying the image on the screen. Any advice? Thanks btw.

Comment: I've fixed the issues I mentioned and posted the code below.  It works fine now so give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the info to the same array as the images, so it will end up like [image, info, image, info] etc.. You're better off adding an object that contains both the image and the info, and then treating it as a single object when you add the contents to the page, rather than adding the images and text in separate functions. Also, you're not clearing the info list, so it would grow exponentially.

Here's a modified example, just after tweaking the bits I mentioned above...

```js
var info = {
myInfo: [],

add: function(imageBlob, artist, title) {
    this.myInfo.push({
        image: imageBlob,
        artist: artist,
        title: title
    });
},

redraw: function() {
    var divForImages = document.getElementById('myImages');

    divForImages.innerHTML = '';

    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    ul.innerHTML = "";

    this.myInfo.forEach((info) => {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.style.width = "200px";
        img.style.height = "200px";
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(info.image);
        divForImages.appendChild(img);

        let li = document.createElement('li');
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.innerHTML = info.artist + " - " + info.title;
    });

},
}

var handlers = {
addImageAndRedraw: function() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var artistField = document.getElementById('artistField');
    var titleField = document.getElementById('titleField');

    if (fileInput.files.length === 1) {
        info.add(fileInput.files[0], artistField.value, titleField.value);
        info.redraw();
    }
}
}

var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handlers.addImageAndRedraw);
```

```html
<h1>My images</h1>

<input id="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="false" value="Select image">
<input id="button" type="button" value="Add image and redraw">

<div>
<input id="artistField" type="text" placeholder="artist">
<input id="titleField" type="text" placeholder="title">
</div>

<hr>

<div id="myImages"></div>

<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks so much. Is there anyway I can display the image and its text underneath it, then the next image underneath that, and so on? Or would that be with CSS?

Comment: The easiest way to fix that is to create a new div for each image & text, similar to what you already have.  Then use CSS to make sure the positioning and padding etc. are suitable.